# How to stop OAuth from auto-logging into a website

Tags: google-chrome, oauth

OAuth is actually useful for me because I use it mainly to not need a password. On the occasions that I don't need to login though, OAuth forces me to log into my (non-existing) account. I will not touch anything, but the moment the website loads, OAuth tries to force me to log in with their tiny popup in the top right corner. It just tries to make me sign into it automatically.

I attempted to hit the CANCEL button but it greyed out when I was about to hit my touchpad. Is there a setting that stops autologin with OAuth?